# Updating a query in a dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

Here is my table in the dataset:

```
SELECT tag_work_field.* FROM tag_work_field
```

I created this query in typed dataset:

```
UPDATE `contacts`.`tag_work_field` SET `work_Field_name` = @work_Field_name WHERE ((`work_Field_name` = @Original_work_Field_name))
```

And I called it: UpdateWorkField

Now I Created my data adepter and update the field :

```
tag_work_field1TableAdapter  Adapter = new  tag_work_field1TableAdapter();
```

Adapter.UpdateWorkField(txtAddWorkField.Text,mysrt);

In this I want update the field with textbox string where field = mystr.

The problem that I'm not geting any update??!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create new object for the data set to call that function.